# Python Add Columns CSV

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, multiple-columns

I'm making a web scraper that scrapes tables from this [website](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/). As you can see, I have it running in a loop that makes a new CSV file for each webpage.

The problem is that since it's making a new webpage, I have like 100 CSV files in the end. How should I compile these? I want it in such a way that it will be a single CSV file having all of the columns(the column from the 1st CSV file would be column A, from the second would be in column B, etc.). Each CSV file only has one column, so I just want to merge all of the files. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
import bs4
count = 1
while count < 1000:
url = "https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/" + str(count)

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

tables = soup.findAll("table")

tableMatrix = []
for table in tables:
    #Here you can do whatever you want with the data! You can findAll table row headers, etc...
    list_of_rows = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
    tableMatrix.append((list_of_rows, list_of_cells))

placeHolder = 0
excelTable = []

for table in tableMatrix:
    for row in table:
        if placeHolder == 0:
            for entry in row:
                excelTable.append(entry)
            placeHolder = 1
        else:
            placeHolder = 0
    excelTable.append('\n')      

for value in excelTable:
    print value
    print '\n'
count += 1  
fl = open(str(count) + '.csv', 'w')

writer = csv.writer(fl)
for values in excelTable:
    writer.writerow(values)

fl.close()
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `pandas` package instead of `csv` -- it's more powerful and it's easier to do things like adding columns

Comment: @SantiagoBenoit Is there any easy fix to do it while in csv?

Comment: What is a single column csv file? If there is only one column, these is nothing being separated. How about you remove all of the irrelevant web scraping code from this question, and instead show a sample data file, and what you want the resulting merged file to look like.  And then hopefully a try at solving the merge problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyexcel. First store the data for column in a list then dynamically store this column data inside another list. The following code will help you to create the list of list dynamically. Once you store all the data in the final_list you can dump it in a pyexcel temporary sheet and later save it into a csv file.

```
import pyexcel as pe
Final_list = []   
for i in range(6): # number of column you want to create
    Final_list.append([])
    for n in range(6): # number of data for a particular column
        Final_list[i].append('col'+str(n)) # data for column

print(Final_list)
sheet = pe.Sheet(Final_list)
print(sheet)
sheet.save_as("Final.csv")
```